# Running my program with command line arguments

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to run my program using the command line. I am trying to return my command line arguments:

```
import System.Environment   
import Data.List  

main :: IO()

main = do  
   args <- getArgs  
   progName <- getProgName  
   putStrLn "The arguments are:"  
   mapM putStrLn args  
   putStrLn "The program name is:"  
   putStrLn progName
```

I am executing the code by calling the main function with my arguments:

```
main argument arguments "more arguements"
```

However, I am getting a complier error:

```
<interactive>:33:6: Not in scope: ‘argument’
<interactive>:33:15: Not in scope: ‘arguments’
```

Is there an issue with how I am calling my function with my arguments?

Comment: are you are calling this in GHCi?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling this in GHCi.

Comment: well Zeta was quicker ;)

Comment: Geez. That was driving me crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You have to use `:main` if you want to simulate command line arguments. `main` alone only executes your `IO ()` action, but doesn't actually build the arguments. For all what GHCi knows, `main` doesn't necessarily need to be `IO ()`, it could be `Int -> Int -> IO ()`.

However, if you use `:main`, GHC will use `main` in the same way it would get invoked during an `runhaskell` call, e.g. with interpreting the following parameters as command line arguments.

Alternatively, you can use `withArgs` from `System.Environment`:

```
ghci> withArgs ["argument", "arguments", "more arguments"] main
```

Comment: That totally makes sense. Thanks for the explanation, Zeta!